# clang fails replacing a statement if it contains a macro

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I'm using clang to try and parse (with the C++ API) some C++ files and make all the case - break pairs use a specific style.

**Example**:

```
**Original**

switch(...)
{
   case 1:
   {
      <code>
   }break;

   case 2:
   {
      <code>
      break;
   }
}

**After replacement**

switch(...)
{
   case 1:
   {
      <code>
      break;
   }

   case 2:
   {
      <code>
      break;
   }
}
```

What I have so far does exactly what I want if the code parts don't contain any macros.
My question is: does clang treat expanded ( if I do a dump of a problematic statement it will show the expanded version ) macros differently? if so how can I get this to work?

Additional info that may help:

I'm using [**Rewriter::ReplaceStmt**](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Rewriter.html#afe268d736bda618e176fc754bb4657a8) to replace the sub-statements of each case with a newly created **CompoundStmt** and I noticed **ReplaceStmt** returns true if the "from" parameter contains a macro and the only way that method returns **true** is if

> [Rewriter::getRangeSize](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Rewriter.html#a73a1da56ec0a9d2a720f087ddd94870c)(from->[getSourceRange](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Stmt.html#a6844392ee6148b5fe821f211b95e5d1b)())

returns -1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the design of [SourceLocation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html).

An article follows:

---

## Macro expansion with clang's SourceLocation

[`SourceLocation`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html) is designed to be flexible enough to handle **both unexpanded locations and macro expanded locations at the same time**.

If the token is the result of an expansion, then there are two different locations to be kept into account: the *spelling location* (the location of the characters corresponding to the token) and the *instantiation location* (the location where the token was used - the macro instantiation point).

Let's take the following simple source file as an example:

```
#define MACROTEST bool

int main() {

    int var = 2;
    switch(var)
    {
       case 1:
       {
          MACROTEST newvar;
       }break;

       case 2:
       {
          MACROTEST newvar;
          break;
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and suppose we want to replace the two declarations statements

```
MACROTEST newvar;
```

with the declaration statement

```
int var = 2;
```

in order to get something like this

```
#define MACROTEST bool

int main() {

    int var = 2;
    switch(var)
    {
       case 1:
       {
          int var = 2;
       }break;

       case 2:
       {
          int var = 2;
          break;
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if we output the AST (*-ast-dump*) we get the following (I'm including an image since it's more intuitive than just uncolored text):

[image: clang AST]

as you can see the location reported for the first `DeclStmt` we're interested in, spans from line 1 to 10: that means clang is reporting in the dump the interval spanning from the macro's line to the point where the macro is used:

```
#define MACROTEST [from_here]bool

int main() {

    int var = 2;
    switch(var)
    {
       case 1:
       {
          MACROTEST newvar[to_here];
       }break;

       case 2:
       {
          MACROTEST newvar;
          break;
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<sub>(notice that the count of characters might not be the same with normal spaces since my text editor used tabs)</sub>

Ultimately, this is triggering the `Rewriter::getRangeSize` failure (`-1`) and the subsequent [`Rewriter::ReplaceStmt`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Rewriter.html#afe268d736bda618e176fc754bb4657a8) `true` return value (which means failure - see documentation).

What is happening is the following: you're receiving a couple of [`SourceLocation`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html) markers where the first is a macro ID ([`isMacroID()`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html#a83c660ad7c57096011c5f40c50b52c7d) would return true) while the latter isn't.

In order to successfully get the extent of the macro-expanded statement we need to take a step back and communicate with the [`SourceManager`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html) which is the query-gateway for all your *spelling locations* and *instantiation locations* (take a step back if you don't remember these terms) needs. I can't be more clear than the detailed description provided [in the documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#details):

> The SourceManager can be queried for information about SourceLocation
>   objects, turning them into either spelling or expansion locations.
>   Spelling locations represent where the bytes corresponding to a token
>   came from and expansion locations represent where the location is in
>   the user's view. In the case of a macro expansion, for example, the
>   spelling location indicates where the expanded token came from and the
>   expansion location specifies where it was expanded.

At this point you should be getting why I explained all this stuff in the first place: **if you intend to use source ranges for your substitution, you need to use the appropriate expansion interval**.

Back to the sample I proposed, this is the code to achieve it:

```
SourceLocation startLoc = declaration_statement->getLocStart();
SourceLocation endLoc = declaration_statement->getLocEnd();

if( startLoc.isMacroID() ) {
    // Get the start/end expansion locations
    std::pair< SourceLocation, SourceLocation > expansionRange = 
             rewriter.getSourceMgr().getImmediateExpansionRange( startLoc );

    // We're just interested in the start location
    startLoc = expansionRange.first;
}

if( endLoc.isMacroID() ) {
  // will not be executed
}

SourceRange expandedLoc( startLoc, endLoc );
bool failure = rewriter.ReplaceText( expandedLoc, 
                                     replacer_statement->getSourceRange() );

if( !failure )
    std::cout << "This will get printed if you did it correctly!";
```

The `declaration_statement` is either one of the two

```
MACROTEST newvar;
```

while `replacer_statement` is the statement used for the replacement

```
int var = 2;
```

The above code will get you this:

```
#define MACROTEST bool

int main() {

    int var = 2;
    switch(var)
    {
       case 1:
       {
          int var = 2;
       }break;

       case 2:
       {
          int var = 2;
          break;
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i.e. a complete and successful substitution of the macro-expanded statement.

---

References:

- [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#the-sourcelocation-and-sourcemanager-classes)
- clang doxygen API
- clang source code

Answer (score 5):

In oder to get the file location related to the macro expansion, an API function can be used to retrieve the information:

```
SourceLocation startLoc = rewriter.getSourceMgr().getFileLoc(
    declaration_statement->getLocStart());
SourceLocation endLoc = rewriter.getSourceMgr().getFileLoc(
    declaration_statement->getLocEnd());
```

This API function does the same as what Marco wrote in his code, but automatically.

If we look at the implementation of the function **getFileLoc**():

This is the description of the function:
*Given Loc, if it is a macro location return the expansion location or the spelling location, depending on if it comes from a macro argument or not.*

```
 SourceLocation getFileLoc(SourceLocation Loc) const {
     if (Loc.isFileID()) return Loc;
         return getFileLocSlowCase(Loc);
 }

SourceLocation SourceManager::getFileLocSlowCase(SourceLocation Loc) const {
    do {
        if (isMacroArgExpansion(Loc))
            Loc = getImmediateSpellingLoc(Loc);
        else
            Loc = getImmediateExpansionRange(Loc).first;
    } while (!Loc.isFileID());
    return Loc;
}
```