# How to get the location of the right parenthesis of a condition in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm using the clang library to do some c++ AST manipulation. I would like to get the location of the right parenthesis of a condition of an `IfStmt`.
I tried:

```
auto condLocEnd = statement->getCond()->getLocEnd();
auto condLoc = Lexer::findLocationAfterToken(condLocEnd, tok::r_paren, sm, LangOptions(), false);
```

Unfortunately `condLoc` is invalid when the condition contains a macro.
Eg: `if(p == NULL)`. I can't figure out how to get the location. How to get it ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the cfe-dev mailing list, I found that this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24223347. I needed to get the expansion location for the `LocEnd()` of my condition expression.